# Cannot Declare Recursive Generic Type in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, recursion

I have previously declared a recursive generic class in C# :

```
  public class CommandSet<commandSetT, commandT> : ICommandSet
               where commandSetT : CommandSet<commandSetT, commandT>
               where commandT : Command
  {

  }
```

Now, I want to do the same in Swift. The reason being that I want the `commandSetT` to have to be a subclass of this base type.

```
public class CommandSet<commandSetT, commandT : Command> : CommandSetProtocol
             where commandSetT : CommandSet<commandSetT, commandT>,
             commandT : Command
{

}
```

But, the compiler complains that the superclass constraint is recursive.

Well, yes it is because I want to ensure that `commandSetT` is a subclass of this class.

Apart from obvious comments like "well Swift is not C#", I would really like to hear from anyone who has any idea how to enforce this requirement.

Comment: I think you should rethink your data model. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: It looks like it is on the roadmap [Swift Generics Manifesto](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md)

Comment: @CodeDifferent - to be able to define a generic parameter type such that it must derive from the base class.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar - that only mentions recursive protocols but we can hope it will extend to classes

Comment: I hope so. At least I don't see any reasons why not.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I found some resolution for myself - may help you as well:

```
protocol A : class {
    associatedtype AType

    var aVar: AType? { get }
}

protocol B : A {
    associatedtype BType : A
}

class Test<AType> : B {
    typealias BType = Test<AType>

    var aVar: AType?
}

class Overriding : Test<String> {
    typealias BType = Overriding
}
```

but it does not works if you delete

```
var aVar: AType? { get }
```

declaration, I don't know why ;)